# get label for for a check input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a radio element that I want to get the  text:

```
<div class="fleft multiplecolumns">
<div class="rdbUniteWrapper" style="line-height:20px">
    <span class="EasilyRadioWrapper EasilyControlWrapper">
        <span class="EasilyRadio EasilyChecked"></span>
        <input id="rdbUnite_106" name="rdbUnite" type="radio" value="106" class="formElementHidden" checked="checked" style="opacity: 0;">
    </span>
    <label for="rdbUnite_106" style="font-weight: bold">kg (kilogramme)</label>
</div>
```

I tried `$('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').next().text();` but it' s not the solution...

What am I doing wrong ?

Cheers

Comment: you just need to add parent before next, and keep the radio name same as html.

Answer (score 1):

`input:radio` is not the sibling of label element, its parent `span` is. thus you need to traverse to parent span, then to next sibling element:

```
 $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').parent().next().text();
```

Comment: Delicate; the slightest change to the HTML blows it up.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution

```
var labelUnite = $('label[for="' + $("input[name='rdbUnite']:checked").attr("id") + '"]').text();
```

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
$('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').parent().next().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am having a radio element that I want to get the text

Since the two are nicely related by `id` = `for`, you can use an attribute value selector:

```
// Assuming `this` is a reference to the radio button element
var label = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
```

Then if you want the text, use `.text()`:

```
var test = label.text();
```

Live example:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {
  alert($('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text());
});
```

```html
Click a radio button to see its label text:
<div>
  <label for="r1">This is for r1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="r2">This is for r2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r2">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="r3">This is for r3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="r3">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

More generally, a radio button element and its label are related in one of two ways:

1. Via `id` = `for`, as in your example
2. Via containment, where the `label` *contains* the `input[type=radio]`

If you want to handle the general case, you can do something like this:

```
// Assuming `this` is the radio button element
var text;
var label = null;
if (this.id) {
    label = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');
}
if (!label || !label[0]) {
    label = $(this).closest('label');
}
text = label && label.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
var label = $("label[for='"+$('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').attr('id')+"']")
```